# Github page build failure

Tags: github-pages

I am creating my website on github page, I am not using jekyll or any of its kind, it's just pure javascript and html css. Why sometime it gives page build failure? what it is building then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default in a github repository, the **gh-pages** branch is build with **Jekyll**.

If you have underscored folders (eg: _myfolder) Jekyll tries to build. If they are not real Jekyll folders, this breaks the build.

If you don't want to process you html/js code, add a **.nojekyll** file at the root of your code. Github will then not try to build, it will just serve your pages as is.

More info in [Github pages doc](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#turning-jekyll-off)

Comment: Thanks, spot on! Here's the original blog post mentioning this feature https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error. I was using only HTML, CSS and JS just like you. Also adding **.nojekyll** made no changes, I was still getting the same error.

Then I figured out the error in my code editor(VS code). VS code shows if there any problems in the code only the bottom left corner.

The thing that caused error was that I was missing a *colon(:)* in my css code.

So check your code once more if it this kind of minor issues.